# Images not loading on razor page

Tags: c#, .net

[image]

I have some images in my razor page, that are stored under wwwroot folder...but for some reason its not working, i added

```
  app.UseStaticFiles();
```

to the StartUp but still doesnt work

my razor page resumed

```
@{
  var apiPath = "http://localhost:5000";
  var imagePath = apiPath + "/StaticFiles/";
  var faceLogoPath = imagePath + "images/facebook-logo.png";
  var instaLogoPath = imagePath + "images/instagram-logo.png";
  var youtubeLogoPath = imagePath + "images/youtube-logo.png";
  var mrvLogoPath = imagePath + "images/logo-mrv-mobile.png";
}
   <td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; line-height: 32px; color: #ff8b22; word-spacing: 0; text-align: left; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;">
        <img
            src="@mrvLogoPath"
            alt="MRV"
            width="90"
            height="26"
            style="display:block; width:90px; height:26px;"
          />
  </td>
```

Comment: https is served over port 5001 by default.  Are you sure port 5000 is serving https traffic?

Comment: Let the runtime decide to use the correct host. Use `var apiPath = "~";`

Comment: tried with both http://5000, and "~", and had the same result =/

Comment: http : // 5000 *

Comment: Why is `wwwroot` underlined red? Is there an error?